# Syntax error on token "void", record expectedJava(1610612940)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that would translate english into pig latin. I have written my code however i keep getting the error "Syntax error on token "void", record expectedJava(1610612940)".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    public String pigLatin(String word){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userin = input.nextLine();
        int InLength = userin.length();
        String firstletter = userin.substring(0, 1);
        if(firstletter.matches(".*[bdgnrs].*"))
        {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
        input.close();
        return firstletter;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can only declare methods within types. You don't have a class declaration - you've just got the import and then a method declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a class to put in you main() method

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mytest {
     
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     pigLatin("baby");
        
  }
  public static String pigLatin(String word){
    
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userin = input.nextLine();
      int InLength = userin.length();
      String firstletter = userin.substring(0, 1);

      if(firstletter.matches(".*[bdgnrs].*")){
           System.out.println("yes");
       }

      input.close();
      return firstletter;
      }
    }
```

With this your code is calling your pigLatin method, but I don't know if code inside is working as you expect

Regards,

Comment: i am trying to have the word that the user input into the terminal be the word that will be translated. however when i try to move the variables such as scanner inputs  string userin and int inLength to outside so more code has access to it it gives me a bunch of errors.

Comment: Yes, you can't access to the values inside the method by the principle of encapsulation, this hide the variables to prevent modifications: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Also if you made a method that do all the logic could be complicated, but you can create some global variables and modify (getter and setter) it in your code, with this, you can use it in any place of your code